# ld: unsupported tapi file type '!tapi-tbd' in YAML file '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd' for x86_64

Tags: xcode, yaml, clang, ld

How can I resolve this issue building AI-Feynman on OS X 12.4 with XCode 13.4?

https://github.com/SJ001/AI-Feynman

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/707071?page=1#715262022

```
/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda3/envs/AI-Feynman/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-gfortran -Wall -g -arch x86_64 -Wall -g -undefined dynamic_lookup -bundle build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/build/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/aifeynman/_symbolic_regress1module.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/build/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/build/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/aifeynman/fortranobject.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/aifeynman/symbolic_regress1.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/build/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/aifeynman/_symbolic_regress1-f2pywrappers.o -L/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda3/envs/AI-Feynman/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2/4.8.5 -L/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda3/envs/AI-Feynman/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2/4.8.5/../../.. -L/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda3/envs/AI-Feynman/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2/4.8.5/../../.. -lgfortran -o aifeynman/_symbolic_regress1.cpython-39-darwin.so
ld: unsupported tapi file type '!tapi-tbd' in YAML file '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd' for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: Command "/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda3/envs/AI-Feynman/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-gfortran -Wall -g -arch x86_64 -Wall -g -undefined dynamic_lookup -bundle build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/build/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/aifeynman/_symbolic_regress1module.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/build/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/build/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/aifeynman/fortranobject.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/aifeynman/symbolic_regress1.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/build/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/aifeynman/_symbolic_regress1-f2pywrappers.o -L/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda3/envs/AI-Feynman/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2/4.8.5 -L/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda3/envs/AI-Feynman/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2/4.8.5/../../.. -L/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda3/envs/AI-Feynman/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2/4.8.5/../../.. -lgfortran -o aifeynman/_symbolic_regress1.cpython-39-darwin.so" failed with exit status
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused by a version 12.0.0 of ld.

```
/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda3/envs/AI-Feynman/bin/ld -v
@(#)PROGRAM:ld  PROJECT:ld64-530
BUILD 05:01:35 Aug  4 2021
configured to support archs: armv6 armv7 armv7s arm64 arm64e arm64_32 i386 x86_64 x86_64h armv6m armv7k armv7m armv7em (tvOS)
LTO support using: LLVM version 12.0.0 (static support for 26, runtime is 27)
TAPI support using: Apple TAPI version 10.0.0 (tapi-1000.10.8)
```

The ld version 13.1.6 does not have the issue.

```
BUILD 11:29:01 May 17 2022
configured to support archs: armv6 armv7 armv7s arm64 arm64e arm64_32 i386 x86_64 x86_64h armv6m armv7k armv7m armv7em
LTO support using: LLVM version 13.1.6, (clang-1316.0.21.2.5) (static support for 28, runtime is 28)
TAPI support using: Apple TAPI version 13.1.6 (tapi-1316.0.7.3)
```